# My javascript statement won't run its else statement even though checkbox isn't checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox that should be being checked every time I click label. However, the js will only run the initial if statement. After that, when .menu-bar-checkbox.checked is false, the else statement won't run. And I am seeing the checkbox become checked.

So basically, after the label fades in, I can't also get it to animate on click afterwards. Thanks for the help!

My html:

```
<ul class="ul-links">
  <li class="hide li-portfolio"><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="hide li-contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<label class="no-pull menu-bar">
    Menu
    <input class="menu-bar-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</label>
```

My js:

```
$(function() {
    var $hide = $('.hide');
    $hide.hide();


    $('label').on('click', function() {

        if ($('.menu-bar-checkbox').checked = true) {
            $hide.fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            $('.ul-links').animate ({
                height: 0,
            }, 1000)
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: `$().checked` won't do anything for you. Not a jQuery object property

Comment: `if ($('.menu-bar-checkbox').is(':checked')) { ...` if you wanna do it for realz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
($('.menu-bar-checkbox').checked = true)
```

to:

```
($('.menu-bar-checkbox')[0].checked == true)
```

Use `==` to check one value against another. And `$('.menu-bar-checkbox')` returns a list of checkboxes matching the `class selection`. (in your case only one). use `[0]` to address the correct one.

And completely in jQuery (as suggested in comments)

```
($('.menu-bar-checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

> Note: the jQuery one will fire on every checkbox that has class `.menu-bar-checkbox` and is selected. The one with `[0]` will only fire on the first checkbox `selected` in the list.

Comment: Might as well just use `.is(':checked')` instead of going from jQuery to the core DOM property, for consistency if nothing else.

Comment: Or `.prop("checked")`.

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks, my jQuery isn't as comprehensive as plain JavaScript.

Comment: the reason is that $(selector) returns an array of jquery objects that match the selector, and checked is not a property of it. [0] gives you the dom node object you are looking for, because in your case there is only one matched element in that array